# "IndexError: only integers, slices ..."

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

Partiendo de un diccionario ({"ticker, "nombre_abreviado"}), pretendo importar a un único DataFrame, utilizando un loop, las cotizaciones de los valores asociados con dichos tickers, renombrando al mismo tiempo las columnas con la clave "nombre_abreviado". Para ello elaboro el siguiente script:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr 
import datetime as dt 

dicc_tickers = {"IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", "TEF.MC":"Telefonica", "R4.MC":"Renta4", "^IBEX":"Ibex35", "^GSPC":"S&P500", 
                "^IXIC":"Nasdaq", "^N225":"Nikkey_225", "^DJI":"DowJons", "^STOXX50E":"Eurostoxx50",  
                "IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", "IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", "IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", 
                'AAPL':"Apple", 'MSFT':"Microsoft", 'GOOG':"Google", "AMZN":"Amazon"}

dfs = []
nombres = []

for (k,v) in dicc_tickers.items():
    cotizaciones_de_ticker = pdr.DataReader(k, 'yahoo', start, end)
    cotizaciones_de_ticker = cotizaciones_de_ticker[["Close"]]
    cotizaciones_de_ticker.columns.values [v]          
    dfs.append(cotizaciones_de_ticker)
    
dfs = iter(dfs)
df_final = next(dfs)
for df_ in dfs:
    df_final = df_final.merge(df_, on='Date')

df_final
```

Me devuelve un error que no entiendo y desearía fijar.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-5282a50bc8d7> in <module>
      9 for (k,v) in dicc_tickers.items():
     10     cotizaciones_de_ticker = pdr.DataReader(k, 'yahoo', start, end)
---> 11     cotizaciones_de_ticker.columns.values [v]
     12 
     13     dfs.append(cotizaciones_de_ticker)

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: Te siguiero que mires esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34952651/only-integers-slices-ellipsis-numpy-newaxis-none-and-intege/44104578)

Comment: ¿Qué pretendías hacer con esa línea que te está dando el error?. No parece que haga nada útil, pues no estás asignando el resultado, y en cambio da un error porque `v` no es un entero sino una cadena. Si simplemente quitas esa línea, el resto funciona sin errores, si bien no estoy seguro de si lo que sale es lo que buscabas.

Comment: La línea 11, pretendo que cambie la etiqueta de la columna del df importado y lo sustituya por el valor de la posición "i" del diccionario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La línea que te da el problema es esta:

```
cotizaciones_de_ticker.columns.values [v]
```

Pues `v` tiene un valor que es una cadena, como por ejemplo `"Iberdrola"`, pero `.columns.values` es una lista, por lo que al intentar acceder a `[v]` da error, ya que las listas sólo pueden ser indexadas con enteros o slices.

Según se aclara en comentarios, lo que se pretendía con esa línea era renombrar la columna llamada "Close" que viene en el dataframe `cotizaciones_de_ticker` para que su nombre sea la cadena que está en `v`. Evidentemente la sintaxis que se ha intentado para esto no es la correcta (y de todas formas no tendría ningún efecto aún si se hubiera usado la sintaxis correcta, porque no se está asignando el resultado a ningún lugar).

Basta cambiar esa línea por:

```
cotizaciones_de_ticker = cotizaciones_de_ticker.rename(columns={"Close": v})
```

Ésta si hace correctamente el renombrado. Un ejemplo de dataframe resultante:

```
>>> print(df_final)

            Iberdrola  Telefonica  Renta4  ...   Microsoft       Google       Amazon
Date                                       ...                                      
2021-01-04     11.905       3.299    7.08  ...  217.690002  1728.239990  3186.629883
2021-01-05     11.720       3.323    6.90  ...  217.899994  1740.920044  3218.510010
2021-01-06     12.230       3.487    6.90  ...  212.250000  1735.290039  3138.379883
2021-01-07     12.285       3.584    6.86  ...  218.289993  1787.250000  3162.159912
2021-01-08     12.505       3.567    6.86  ...  219.619995  1807.209961  3182.699951
2021-01-12     11.995       3.599    6.80  ...  214.929993  1746.550049  3120.830078
2021-01-13     12.110       3.947    6.80  ...  216.339996  1754.400024  3165.889893
2021-01-14     12.005       3.835    6.80  ...  213.020004  1740.180054  3127.469971
2021-01-15     11.915       3.750    6.80  ...  212.649994  1736.189941  3104.250000
2021-01-19     11.820       3.751    6.88  ...  216.440002  1790.859985  3120.760010
2021-01-20     11.730       3.772    6.92  ...  224.339996  1886.900024  3263.379883
2021-01-21     11.700       3.675    6.92  ...  224.970001  1891.250000  3306.989990
2021-01-22     11.660       3.637    6.92  ...  225.949997  1901.050049  3292.229980
2021-01-25     11.685       3.587    7.00  ...  229.529999  1899.400024  3294.000000
2021-01-26     11.615       3.656    7.00  ...  232.330002  1917.239990  3326.129883
2021-01-27     11.360       3.709    7.00  ...  232.899994  1830.790039  3232.580078
2021-01-28     11.425       3.613    6.96  ...  238.929993  1863.109985  3237.620117
2021-01-29     11.185       3.554    7.00  ...  231.960007  1835.739990  3206.199951
```